# how is receive implemented and defined

Tags: scala

Sometimes there is so magic happens that I break my head figuring out on what the compiler does. For example in akka, `receive` is defined as:

```
def receive: Receive
type Receive = Actor.Receive
```

and `Receive` is defined as:

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

then we declare `receive` as:

```
def receive = {
     case "a" => //do something
     case "b" => //do something
     case _ => //default
}
```

I am aware of `PartialFunction` but what I dont get is that how does it apply the message to `receive`. Aren't we suppose to provide `apply` and `isDefinedAt` because `receive` returns a `PartialFunction`?

Syntactically how does it apply `receive` to the message? DOes it do something like `message match receive` or something?

Comment: The `receive` method does not handle incoming messages, it supplies the `PartialFunction` that handles incoming messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will automatically generate the `isDefinedAt` from the body and `apply` is the body itself. Where a partial function is expected, you can just write a block that consist of case expressions and the compiler will turn it into a partial function.

```
scala> val f: PartialFunction[Any, Any] = {
     | case x: String => 3
     | }
f: PartialFunction[Any,Any] = <function1>

scala> f.isDefinedAt("foo")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> f.isDefinedAt(23)
res2: Boolean = false
```

**edit**:

In the underlying akka code, receive will be called to set the handler function once and then for every arriving message it tries to apply the receive method and otherwise calls `unhandled` (see links).

So the handler will only be called, if it can handle the message, otherwise the message will be put in the deadletters mailbox.

**edit2**:

These are the relevant sections in the akka code:

Call handler if defined, otherwise call unhandled:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L496

unhandled:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L545

Comment: your `else` block is not entirely true.  If the partial function is not defined for the message, the `unhandled` function of the actor is invoked.  This default behavior for this function is to either fail with a akka.actor.DeathPactException (in case of an unhandled akka.actor.Terminated message) or to publishe an akka.actor.UnhandledMessage to the actor's system's akka.event.EventStream.   This function is overridable if different behavior is desired, but the point is that the message does not go to deadletter by default.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the links to the relevant code. It was only fore illustration, but thanks I will edit it.